# Using Ajax to send a request. Despite using preventDefault, the page is reloading

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I am writing a Flask App in which I want to be able to use a form to input information into a database without refreshing the page.
Here is my form:

```
    <form id="vocab_form">
    <label for="name">Word:</label>
    <input type="text" id="word" name="word">

    <label for="def">Definition</label>
    <input type="text" id="def" name="def">

    <input type="submit" value="Add Term">
    </form>
```

Here is the script I am using to send the request. It is embedded in the html file containing the form.

```
<script>
$(document).on('submit', '#vocab_form', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/',
        data:{
            word:$(#word).val(),
            def:$(#def).val()
        },
        success:function(){
            alert('success');
        }
    }) 
});
```

Here is the route to which I am sending the form data. It calls functions in another file to input the data into my database and to collect some information online with which to render the page.

```
    @app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def hello():
    if request.method == "POST":
        word = request.form["word"]
        definition = request.form["def"]
        query.add_word(word, definition)
        message="Word added successfully! {} means {}".format(word, definition)
    else:
        message="no form data"
    wordlist=query.get_all_words()
    lines = web_functions.get_les_mis()
    return render_template("home.html", message=message, wordlist=wordlist, lines=lines)
```

Although my script includes the instruction to prevent the default submit behavior for the form, the page reloads each time I submit the form. I want to prevent this. Any advice or insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: Any errors in the browser's Console? That would prevent scripts from running, potentially

Comment: If you did check the console I'm thinking you're going to see an error because `$(#word)` should be `$("#word")` - you forgot the quote marks. Same on the following line. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vocab_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/',
            data:{
                word:$(#word).val(),
                def:$(#def).val()
            },
            success:function(){
                alert('success');
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: `Try this instead`... because...? What's your reason? Why does this solve the problem? Please always explain the answer then people don't have to guess or just practise cargo-cult programming. Anyway as far as I can see it's functionally identical to the original, so unlikely to achieve anything - but please point out anything I may have missed.